# I need a word or expression to describe the attitude of "Since they do it, it shouldn't be a big deal if we do it"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I know the title is extremely vague so I'll try to explain it with an example. For example, if a company makes some errors, and then instead of acknowledging the responsibility for their mistakes, they instead say things like: "Even Apple makes mistakes, how can you expect our products to be 100% error free". What kind of language is this called?

It's a form of negative language. Other words I thought were "pessimistic" or "accusatory" or "complacent", but I'm not entirely sure if these words can be used to describe the example I gave most accurately.

Comment: I would describe it this way: "Oh, look—their house has a pox on it, too, so the one on ours doesn't matter."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of response can be described as an **[apologia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apologia)**, i.e., a justification or rationale offered in lieu of contrition. Different from an apology, the term implies that a defense is presented, which seems to fit the situation you describe.

Answer (score 4):

This is usually called **rationalisation**.

Though not the only sense, the one involved here is

> rationalisation NOUN mass noun
>
> 1 The action of attempting to explain or justify behaviour or an
>   attitude with logical reasons, even if these are not appropriate.
>
> *most people are prone to self-deceptive rationalisation*

[[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rationalization)]

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalization_(psychology)) is perhaps better worded:

> [R]ationalization or rationalisation (also known as making excuses) is
>   a defense mechanism in which controversial behaviors [or poor decisions /
>   errors] ... are justified and explained in a seemingly
>   rational or logical manner to avoid the true explanation.... It is
>   also an informal fallacy of reasoning.

[adjusted to shift the emphasis from the psychological field to that of general practice]

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly that this fits the way I read the OP question.  I might add, that the word's verb form, rationalize ,  is also appropriate and common as is the gerund form of the verb, rationalizing, as a name for a ongoing action.

Comment: Ah, I think this is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would call an attitude like that signified to be **dismissive.**

> Dismissive b. Tending to dismiss from consideration as insignificant; characterized by rejection, contemptuous.

[OED-3](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/54792?redirectedFrom=dismissive#eid)

> The complaint also quotes a May e-mail from CEO Elon Musk that seemed **dismissive** of problems at the factory

[Technica](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2017/11/tesla-facing-potential-class-action-lawsuit-for-racial-discrimination/)